# Passing complex object with RouteValueDictionary using RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass a Complex Object(Object within an object) to my action method using RedirectToAction method but it is returned null. Is there a way to do this using RouteValueDictionary?

My Model:

```
public class ModelUser
    {
        public UserLine User { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserLine
    {

        public int? UserID { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

My Action method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(UserCreate model)
        {
            var valDTORegister = new RegisterLine() { Email = model.Email, Password = model.Password, OwnerType = model.OwnerType };
            var result = await PostRequest<RegisterLine, UserLine>("http://localhost:10853/", "api/user/Create", valDTORegister);

            var usermodel = new ModelUser();
            usermodel.User = result;

            return RedirectToAction("ProfileUser", new RouteValueDictionary(usermodel));

        }

        public ActionResult ProfileUser(ModelUser usermodel) //User object is null
        {
            return View();
        }
```

I tried passing only UserLine object using RouteValueDictionary and the values has been properly passed to my ProfileUser method. This is good but I want to pass the whole ModelUser object because I may need to add more object within it.

Answer (score 0):

you can connect the `ProfileUser` page to model `ModelUser` and than call this view like this:

```
return View("ProfileUser", usermodel);
```

the action shold be without parameters

```
public ActionResult ProfileUser()
{
   return View();
}
```

And all data is in the model ("ModelUser") of ProfileUser